# How to pass id to a function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

JavaScript:

```
function executeOnclick() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) { 
            myFunction(xhttp);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET","http://try.com/students/search.php?stud_id=?" +x , true);
    xhttp.send();
}   

function myFunction(obj){
    var xmlDoc = obj.responseText;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id");

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="1210" onclick="executeOnclick()" onload="myElement(this);" 
     class="Cpictures" src="1.jpg" width=50px height=75px alt="Robert" />
```

This code doesn't work. I want that when I call the *myFunction* function, I get the Id of the image and pass it to my API. How do I do that?

Comment: using "this" as a functions parameter name is probably not the best idea - in fact, it wont work at all

Comment: the id would be `this.id` not `"this.id"`

Comment: I edited my code, can you check if it's what you meant? Also, why would passing "this" wont work?

Comment: How does your function `myElement` get the reference to `this`?

Comment: not quite ... `function myElement(x){ var getID = document.getElementById(x.id);}` should do it

Comment: Im not sure. that's im trying to understand. I dont know how to let myElement function read and get the image id and pass it.

Comment: Change the `onload` function to this `onload="myElement(this.id);"` and the JS to `function myElement(val){alert(val); }  `

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `function myElement()` doesn't accept any parameters. Passing `this` passes a reference of the object from which it's called (specifically, in this case, an instance of `HTMLImageElement`). But your function isn't looking for anything at all.

Changing your function from:

```
function myElement(){
    var getID = document.getElementById(this.id);
}
```

to:

```
function myElement(obj){
    //Insert code you want here. I printed the id to console for example.
    console.log(obj.id);
}
```

Will allow you to access the object's id (And any other part of the id you want to use).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpqh6s7a/)

Comment: It works perfectly. But im having trouble because it will alert me the object id before I click the picture.

Comment: Then remove the alert, and put whatever code you wanted in. I meant this as an example, not as a copy-pastable solution.

Comment: @SatejS Sorry, hadn't expanded the comments to see yours.

Comment: Sorry bout that. I edited my code, do I pass the element I got from myElement function that way?